# Variable string matching

Tags: ruby

I have a program that accepts command line inputs. The input is similar to this:

```
ruby myprogram.rb --option1 --option2=foo
```

Right now, I split the command by spaces and keep an array of commands. For example, this would be the array for the example above:

```
['option1','option2=foo']
```

In the code, there is a list of valid commands:

```
valid_cmd = %w(
    --option1
    --option2
    --option3
)
```

Using the list of parsed commands, what is the best way to check that a inputted command is valid? There is also a more difficult component to this. Let's say `option2` has optional arguments. For example, `--option2=anArgument` is just as valid as `--option2` alone. On the other hand, `option3` has mandatory arguments - ie. `--option3=foo` is valid but `--option3` is not. How can we account for this as well?

Comment: Use OptionParser: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html

Comment: What is a good way to require an equal sign for arguments? For ex, the section on required arguments in the docs allows for this:
`-r library`

How can I declare that invalid? I want a valid command to be like this:
`-r=library`

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Try what maro says.